# calling php function from html

Tags: php

i'm a beginner to php. i need to use php function which process some other pages and to display

dynamic result as javascript when a HTML button click is triggered .Is it possible?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jamie Lewis's answer is a good one, but I will say that he is addressing to JavaScript while answering. I think the pure PHP solution is following:

You create a PHP file (myFile.php) where you get some arguments with GET method. And Your HTML form should have a button that calls following:

```
myFile.php?agrument1=10&argument2=20
```

SO HTML will pass arguments to your PHP file and you should get that arguments and call a function with that arguments.

For more details see (sending arguments with GET/POST methods ).

Answer (score 3):

Yes. This is possible through a collection of technologies known as **[AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)**, i.e. using Javascript's asynchronous communication ability.

There are already a number of pre-built libraries that allow you to do this with ease. One of the most common is [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/), also just google AJAX and you will find hundereds of libraries, tutorials and guides to help you.